# Heroku not loading proper Bootstrap CSS files from Rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, asset-pipeline

I tried deploying my rails app with newly added bootstrap to it and a lot of the view in my app is missing.

Here are some errors I got when deploying to Heroku

```
      Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       Invalid CSS after "@iconSpritePath:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " asset-path("tw..."
       (in /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
       (sass):4712
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1145:in `expected'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1083:in `expected'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1065:in `expr!'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:793:in `pseudo'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:671:in `simple_selector_sequence'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:639:in `_selector'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:618:in `selector'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:155:in `directive'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:552:in `block_child'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:545:in `block_contents'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:82:in `stylesheet'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:27:in `parse'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/engine.rb:342:in `_to_tree'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/compressor.rb:16:in `compress'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:243:in `block in css_compressor='
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:193:in `block in evaluate'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `each'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `new'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:19:in `block in compile'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:219:in `block in each_logical_path'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:206:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each_entry'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204:in `block in each_file'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each_file'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217:in `each_logical_path'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
       /tmp/build_d0cqakcvbcp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
       Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
       Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
       Please see this article for troubleshooting help:
       http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting
-----> WARNINGS:
       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       ruby '2.0.0'
       # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information."
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 34.4MB
-----> Launching... done, v11
```

I also think this may have something to do with it. I got this error when running a `heroku run rake db` command

```
Running `rake pg:reset` attached to terminal... up, run.8011
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
```

Comment: Your sass is invalid, read the error and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not error it is WARNING.
Which says you have plugin that will no longer be supported in Rails 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap-sass or just sass? It seems that the trace indicates that sass is parsing your css as scss. Try disabling sass:

```
group :assets do
    # gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

If that doesn't work, maybe there really is an error in the css.

edit: the deprecation warning seems unrelated to me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be trying to use the ruby asset_path function in the SASS file to indicated the source of the iconsprite image.

Try using the absolute url instead, i.e. "/assets/sprite_image.png"

The warning is unrelated, it is the SASS compiler crash that caused the problem.